# RabbitMQ delayed message when there is an exception

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm using the plugin (https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2015/04/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq) and it works well. I send a message with X seconds of delay, and it's processed with X seconds of delay.

The problem is in the process logic. If it works well (happy path) I don't have issues. But if the process fails, what I expect is that the message is requeued to be processed with the same delay, but it is processed inmediately.

Is there a way to requeue the message automatically with the original specified delay in case of an exception?

Answer (score 2):

No; the delay is not applicable for retries; if message order is not important, you can re-publish the message to the tail of the queue.

Or, you can configure a retry interceptor with a fixed back off.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#retry

> Spring Retry provides a couple of AOP interceptors and a great deal of flexibility to specify the parameters of the retry (number of attempts, exception types, backoff algorithm, and others). Spring AMQP also provides some convenience factory beans for creating Spring Retry interceptors in a convenient form for AMQP use cases, with strongly typed callback interfaces that you can use to implement custom recovery logic. ...

**EDIT**

Using a `RabbitTemplate` instead of a message-driven listener:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So69020120Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69020120Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    Processor processor;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void sched() {
        try {
            while (this.processor.process()) {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        return new RabbitTransactionManager(cf);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0,  4).forEach(i -> template.convertAndSend("queue", "good"));
            template.convertAndSend("queue", "fail");
            IntStream.range(0,  4).forEach(i -> template.convertAndSend("queue", "good"));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("queue");
    }

}

@Component
class Processor {

    private final RabbitTemplate template;

    private final AtomicBoolean fail = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    Processor(RabbitTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
        template.setChannelTransacted(true);
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean process() {
        String data = (String) template.receiveAndConvert("queue");
        if (data == null) {
            System.out.println("No More Messages");
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println(data);
        if (data.equals("fail") && this.fail.getAndSet(false)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("test");
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

```
good
good
good
good
fail
java.lang.RuntimeException: test
    at com.example.demo.Processor.process(So69020120Application.java:86)
    at com.example.demo.Processor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6adeaa38.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.example.demo.Processor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bad30db1.process(<generated>)
    at com.example.demo.So69020120Application.sched(So69020120Application.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
fail
good
good
good
good
No More Messages
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. What I need is to consume messages every X time. If I use a listener, it's listening all the time, so every time a message arrives it's processed. What do you suggest?
I read about implementing a chron and run a consumer, but it involves managing the ack manually. 

Something like:
1) Give messages total
2) Process this total (if a message is rejected, I need to process it in the next chron execution, not in the current one).

Comment: You can use a `RabbitTemplate` Instead of a using a message-driven listener, to retrieve messages on a schedule. See `receive()` and `receiveAndConvert()`. Run it in a transaction so the message will be requeued if the processing fails

Comment: But in that case, how can I manage the transaction individually for every message in every chron execution (trying to process all the pending message in every execution)?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thanks for your time Gary. Your example is great. I have a question. The "fail" was processed twice, but only threw an exception with the first one? If that is the case, all failed message will be retried once and considered valid, right? Suppose that I need to retry until TTL is reached. In that case, every chron execution will be executing until there is no more messages, or until all the failed messages reach their ttl?

Comment: This was just a demonstration to show how a failure can be used to stop processing and redelivered on the next schedule - i.e. to simulate a transient problem. I set the boolean so that the failed message would succeed on the next delivery.